# SimpleSAMLphp OpenID Consumer

Tags: php, authentication, openid

I'm using SimpleSAMLphp as an OpenID Consumer and no openID provider I tried seems to work.
I always get the following error:

```
Exception during login: SimpleSAML_Error_BadRequest: BADREQUEST('%REASON%' => 
             'Not a valid OpenID: \'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id\'')
```

or:

```
 Exception during login: SimpleSAML_Error_BadRequest: BADREQUEST('%REASON%' => 
             'Not a valid OpenID: \'https://me.yahoo.com\'')
```

I tried my ID's with other web pages and they work fine.

I'm Using apache 2.2 & php5.3 and a cert from valid CA. Any clues on how I should approach the problem ? anyone got the same problem? I also tried to understand why the authn_request returned by the library is null...

Comment: Please include the contents of your config files as stated by the INSTALL.txt file (https://github.com/ColdTrick/simplesaml/blob/master/INSTALL.txt)

Comment: In my authsources.php I just use the default config:  
'yahoo' => array(
        'openid:OpenIDConsumer',
        'target' => 'https://me.yahoo.com',
        'attributes.ax_required' => array(
                'http://axschema.org/contact/email',
        ),
        'extension.args' => array(
        ),
    ),

Answer (score 0):

my authsources is just defult values plus yahoo :

```
'openid' => array(
    'openid:OpenIDConsumer',
    'attributes.required' => array('nickname'),
    'attributes.optional' => array('fullname', 'email',),
    // 'sreg.validate' => FALSE,
   'attributes.ax_required' => array('http://axschema.org/namePerson/friendly'),
   'attributes.ax_optional' => array('http://axschema.org/namePerson','http://axschema.org/contact/email'),
    // Prefer HTTP redirect over POST
    // 'prefer_http_redirect' => FALSE,
),

'yahoo' => array(
    'openid:OpenIDConsumer',
    'target' => 'https://me.yahoo.com',
    'attributes.ax_required' => array(
            'http://axschema.org/contact/email',
    ),
    'extension.args' => array(
    ),
),

'google' => array(
    'openid:OpenIDConsumer',
    // Googles OpenID endpoint.
    'target' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id',
    // Custom realm
    // 'realm' => 'http://*.example.org',
    // Attributes that google can supply.
    'attributes.ax_required' => array(
        //'http://axschema.org/namePerson/first',
        //'http://axschema.org/namePerson/last',
        //'http://axschema.org/contact/email',
        //'http://axschema.org/contact/country/home',
        //'http://axschema.org/pref/language',
    ),
    // custom extension arguments
    'extension.args' => array(
        //'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0' => array(
        //  'mode' => 'popup',
        //  'icon' => 'true',
        //),
    ),
),
```